# Getting User not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:********0900:

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I am trying to access AWS lending API using postman, but I am getting following error:

[image]

My postman setup is below:

[image]

And my IAM user setup is below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current setup only allows the role `AmazonLendingAPIRole` to access the API. You are accessing the API using the user `AmazonLendingUser` which only has access to assume the role. What you need to do is attach the policy allowing the `execute-api` permissions directly to your user to allow the access through.

More information can be found in the [following documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-and-attach-iam-policy.html).